# How to take backup of BugTracker.net?

Tags: backup, bugtracker.net

I want to take backup of BugTracker.Net hosted on my local and restore it to a new machine ?

Has any one clue about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the database, do a regular Microsoft SQL Server backup and restore (or whetever your hosting company lets you do).

Beyond the database, you probably want to make a copy of the Web.config, because you will be transferring some of those settings to a new machine, and you want a copy of any files that you have customized, like in the "custom" folder.